# Is there a term for when $d(f(x),x)$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, metric-spaces, terminology

Let $f:X\rightarrow X,$ where X is a metric space with metric $d$. Is there a term for $f$ when it satisfies:
$$\left\{d(f(x),x)|x\in V\right\}$$ is bounded? It's sort of like saying $f$ is "tied down," does anyone know of this in the literature?

Comment: First of all, $x$ and $f(x)$ do not live in the same space, secondly there is no minus in a metric space. Do you mean to take $V,W$ normed spaces and $V,W\subseteq U$ are subvector spaces?

Comment: This is true, though worth noting that if they were in the same space, $\operatorname{dist}(x,y)= |x-y|$ is a common shorthand, I believe referred to sometimes as Polish notation.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes, I fixed it. Edit: I actually took a more general statement with metric spaces instead, but your critique was definitely valid.

Comment: @MW Thanks, I was not aware of this notation (I've never seen this used in any text). Do you know, is there a particular community where this is common?

Comment: @MilesGould Sorry, the minus made me believe you were interested in normed spaces. If you want, you could replace the codomain by $W$, you would just need to assume that $V,W$ are both contained in some larger common metric space to have some distance.

Comment: I don’t know a specific term. You might say that $f$ is (uniformly) a bounded distance from the identity map.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I'm starting to second-guess myself on whether this was really that common, though I feel certain I saw it a number of times back when I was studying analysis on metric spaces and geometric function theory.spaces.  Not sure about the name "Polish notation" either tbh.  I've been inactive in mathematics for quite a few years unfortunately so my memory is a little foggy on some of these things.

Comment: @MW No worries, I am from a different corner of analysis and was just curious where it is common. I'll ask some of my friends that are working more often in the metric setting. It is clearly a convenient notation if it is understood what we mean.

Comment: It is called "bounded displacement" property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This notion is widely used in metric and coarse geometry, and especially in geometric group theory; usually it's just called "a map uniformly close to the identity". More generally, if you have two maps $f, g$ between metric spaces $X, Y$, they are said to be uniformly close, or just "close", or "proximal",.. (notations vary between authors) if distance between images of an element is uniformly bounded: $$d_Y(f(x), g(x)) \leq D$$.

This class of maps has a useful property. Suppose there's a map $f$ between two metric spaces $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$, then if two (positive, real) constants $C, D$ exist such that $$C^{-1} \cdot d_Y(f(x), f(x')) - D \leq d_X(x, x') \leq C \cdot d_Y(f(x), f(x')) + D;$$
and for every $y \in Y$  there exist some $x \in X$ with $e(y, f(x)) \leq D$. Such maps are called quasi-isometries; if you drop second condition, it would be a quasi-isometric embedding. Under this condition, there exist a map $\text{"}f^{-1}\text{"}$ with the property that both $f^{-1} f$ and $f f^{-1}$ are uniformly close (in the sense above) to identity maps of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Such a map is not unique, but it *is* unique up to uniform closeness.

If you want, you can read some parts of *Geometric group theory: An Introduction* by Clara Löh for more context (as far as I remember, it's freely available), or any other book on geometric group theory.